# Can you you use conditional statements in other conditional statements?

Tags: java, if-statement, switch-statement

My question is simple, will the following code work, if it can't is there a way to accomplish the same effect

```
int day = 5; 
    String dayString; 

    switch (if (day > 0) { 
    case 1: 
        dayString = "Monday"; 
        day++;
        break; 
    case 2: 
        dayString = "Tuesday"; 
        day++;
        break; 
    case 3: 
        dayString = "Wednesday"; 
        day++;
        break; 
    case 4: 
        dayString = "Thursday"; 
        day++;
        break; 
    case 5: 
        dayString = "Friday"; 
        day++;
        break; 
    case 6: 
        dayString = "Saturday"; 
        day++;
        break; 
    case 7: 
        dayString = "Sunday"; 
        day++;
        break; 
    default: 
        dayString = "Invalid day"; 
        day++;
        break; 
    } 
    System.out.println(dayString);
```

The output should be friday, basically my question is can you put if statements or while or for or do or other statements within the parameters of the respective statements.

Comment: "will the following code work" What happens when you run it?

Comment: What is the purpose of `if (day > 0)`? just `switch (day) {...}`

Comment: No it would not work. It also would not compile

Comment: Did you even count your parentesises before asking as you obviously didn't try this...

Comment: What difference do you want the `if (day > 0)` part to make? Right now, what you are describing is just a `switch (day) { ... }` statement. Is there something you want to happen when `day` is less than or equal to 0?

Answer (score 1):

Java's syntax  has a number of different structures. Of particular relevance here are *expressions* and *statements*.

An expression is something that has a value. A statement is an instruction to do something (*).

`if` is a statement. Its general syntax is:

```
if (expression) statement
```

(The `{}` is a kind of statement too, which is why you can use braces to surround the code you want to execute).

`expression` has to be of type `boolean` or `Boolean`.

`switch` is also a statement. Its general syntax is:

```
switch (expression) {
  // ...
}
```

The expression has to be of type `int`, `char`, `short`, `byte` (or their boxed counterparts), `String` or `enum`. You can't use `boolean`, `long`, `float` or `double`.

Because the switch needs an expression in the parentheses, you can't use a statement there.

---

(*) Some expressions can "do something" too, that is, they have a side effect, for example `i++`. These are special expressions in the Java language called `StatementExpression`s, which can be written as a statement by adding a semicolon: `i++;` is legal because it meaningfully does something, `i;` is not.

Comment: The expression in if has to be of type boolean. In switch it can be of other types.

Answer (score 0):

the above code will not work...there is syntax error in that code.you cannot add an if condition inside the braces of switch ...it expects a variable to evaluate ...the conditions are given using the case statements...to get friday as output simple put the variable 'day' inside the switch braces--like this-> switch(day)

Comment: you cannot add if conditions inside do, while, for loop's curly braces also...only inside the loop body